# Flask - Single Entry Point for API Crud Service

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flask, crud

I'm trying to implement a single entry point for a RESTFull CRUD service using Flask with a generic URL routing. 
Having an URL like '/api/book/1' should load my BookController (app/controllers/book.py) and call read() method. 
A sample code of what I would like to achieve, but actually it fails to load my modules:

```
@app.route('/api/<controller>/<id>')
@app.route('/api/<controller>')
def api(controller, id = None): 
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if id is None:
                action = 'list'
            else:
                action = 'read'
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            action = 'create'
        elif request.method == 'PUT':
            action = 'update'
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            action = 'delete'
        else: 
            page_not_found()
        module = importlib.import_module('app.controllers.' + controller)
        ctrl = getattr(module, controller.capitalize() + 'Controller')
        instance = ctrl()
        method = getattr(instance, action)
        return method()
    except ImportError as e:
        page_not_found('Invalid request')
```

Quite n00b with Python and Flask, I know :-)

EDIT: 
I get an " ImportError: cannot import name 'Book' "
EDIT 2: 
inside app/controllers/ I have two files:

**init**.py

```
# __init__.py
__all__ = ["book"]
```

book.py

```
from app.models import Book
import json
class BookController():

    data = [Book('Awesome Title', '', 'fa-bar').toJson(), Book('Once upon a time', 'foo', 'fa-paper').toJson()]

    def list(self):
        return json.dumps(self.data)
```

EDIT 3:
Might this be a good approach for routing API requests?

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: Please include the errors you get or describe the expected behavior, compared to what is currently happening. For one thing, you have not included the `methods` argument in the route decorator. IE `@app.route("/endpoint", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])` -- By default only GET is allowed when this argument is not provided.

Comment: @sytech Thanks for the suggestion, anyway actually I am only trying to list my books, so I'm still not having problems with methods

Comment: Your `ImportError` indicates just what it means.. indicating that `Book` doesn't exist in `app.controllers` -- Maybe double check that? (case-sensitivity matters) That is, assuming the error comes from the line `module = importlib.import_module('app.controllers.' + controller)` and not someplace else.

Comment: @sytech Yes, that import fails, and debugging with pdb I can see that the variable "controller" contains "book", but in the error it says it cannot find "Book", what I'm missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean that the variable `controller` "contains" `book`?  Is `controller` a class?  It sounds like you may want to import the controller class, if that's the case.  Also notice that you said it contains `book` not `Book`. Imports are case-sensitive. If you try to import a name from a module, it must be defined globally. Perhaps it would be best if you update your question with the related content from the `app.controllers` module.

Comment: @sytech `controller` is the string I get from url, I don't know why from `importlib.import_module('app.controllers.book')` it says it cannot import `Book`

Comment: I see. Your import error may actually be originating in the `book.py` file. IE `from app.models import Book` Please update your question with the full traceback. (see before I mentioned "assuming the error comes from the line...") -- Is `Book` defined in `app.models` ? If it is defined, this may indicate that you have a conflicting import issue. Does your `models` module by chance import `app`? And your `app` import `models`? Or something like that?

Comment: @sytech Definitely it was an conflicting import error, I'll update the question just to know if this is a good approach

Comment: Flask has [some docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/) on how you should package your applications and specifically addresses what I believe your problem is... While not directly related to your question, it may be worthwhile to rethink the approach IMO. But that may be geared more towards a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/),  as opposed to an SO question.